# Multiple SqlString actions at different sequences in Wix

Tags: sql-server, wix, wix3

I'd like to execute SQL strings at two different sequences in the InstallExecuteSequence.

The problem is that it seems if you use the supplied `<sql:SqlString \>`, they get bundled into the 'InstallSqlData' action.

Is there a way to specify that certain SqlString elements get executed at a different stage (so that I can run a separate custom action in between)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

You might think you could add a new CustomAction tag pointing to Wix's Sql CA and schedule it at a different point in the InstallExecuteSequence. Unfortunately, both instances of the CA will iterate over the same rows in the same tables, so the effect will be to execute each SqlString twice.